# how to send log at the end of script or when invoked? using logger module

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is the logger module and SMTPHandler
which when i register it sends email on every log.

is there a way to tell the SMTPHandler class to "store" the logs and only send upon called or  at the end of script

Comment: Do you mean the `logging` module? Anyway, yes, you could write your own handler that stores messages, and use the `atexit` hooks to send them when your program terminates. Do note that those hooks may not get called if your program crashes.

Comment: Yes, i ment logger module, can u provide example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom handler that holds on to log records instead of emitting them directly:

```
import atexit
import logging


class SpoolingHandler(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, level, *, atexit_function) -> None:
        super().__init__(level)
        self.records = []
        if atexit_function:
            atexit.register(atexit_function, self.records)

    def handle(self, record) -> bool:
        self.records.append(record)
        return True


def send_email(records):
    print(f"Would now send an email with {len(records)} records:")
    for record in records:
        print(record)
    print("----")


def main():
    handler = SpoolingHandler(logging.INFO, atexit_function=send_email)
    logging.basicConfig(handlers=[handler], level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info("Hello")
    logging.warning("Oh no :(")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This prints out

```
Would now send an email with 2 records:
<LogRecord: root, 20, so73483195.py, 28, "Hello">
<LogRecord: root, 30, so73483195.py, 29, "Oh no :(">
----
```